# transforming dates from yyyy-mm-dd to dd/mm/yyyy catering for null or empty dates in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I wanted to change the order of dates from yyyy-mm-dd to dd/mm/yyyy but cater for null or empty dates
I used the code

```
<!--         Data Submitted -->
<xsl:template match="data_submitted">
<data_submitted>
    <xsl:if test="data_submitted != ''">
            <xsl:value-of select=
           "concat(substring(.,9), '/',
                  (substring(.,6,2)), '/',
                 substring(.,1,4))"
           />
    </xsl:if>
</data_submitted>   
</xsl:template>
<!--                                           -->
```

but this omitted dates altogether. Leaving out the  resulted in the null dates appearing as // in my result. I'm sure I have probably got the if in the wrong place or something, but I want a  tag to appear even if it is empty.

Any suggestions?

#### Update:

Apologies everyone, I should have given the initial xml as I was testing for null or empty and there were actually spaces in the element, so my initial translation would have worked if I just put in the number of spaces. The original xml is: `data_submitted>        </data_submitted>` with 8 spaces.
`test="data_submitted != '        '"`
is what was required or:
`test=".!= ''"`, each with 8 spaces.

Answer (score 1):

There a "tiny" mistake..Compare with this (corrected) transform if you  get it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="data_submitted">
        <data_submitted>
            <xsl:variable name="year" select="substring-before(.,'-')"/>
            <xsl:variable name="month" select="substring-before(substring-after(.,'-'),'-')"/>
            <xsl:variable name="day" select="substring-after(substring-after(.,'-'),'-')"/>

            <xsl:if test=".!=''">
                <xsl:value-of select=
                    "concat($day,'/',
                    $month,'/',
                    $year)"
                    />
            </xsl:if>
        </data_submitted>   
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied on this sample input:

```
<data>
    <data_submitted>
        yyyy-mm-dd
    </data_submitted>
    <data_submitted/>
</data>
```

Returns:

```
<data>
   <data_submitted>dd/mm/yyyy</data_submitted>
   <data_submitted/>
</data>
```

---

Got the mistake?

The template is already in the context of the `data_submitted`, so inside the template test you just need `.` to refer to the matched element.

However, I suggest you to test empty `text()` nodes in the template context above as follows:

```
test="boolean(./text())"
```

or (the same in your context)

```
test="boolean(text())"
```

This will return false if, and only if, the text string length is `0`.

Comment: I will try replacing data_submitted with a dot . as the result you show looks good.

Comment: Thanks. Think of accepting the answer which best fits you requirements and, in general, upvote responsibly the answers working and useful.

Comment: I tried the dot, still no dice, then 'test=boolean(text())' and it still gave me the '/ /' when the data_submitted element had nothing in it.

Comment: Which processor are you using? I test my transform with a compliant one (Saxon) and it's working perfectly.

Comment: Otherwise, you should show your input document and most of the transform you can; we can't keep guessing.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't explained what you mean by "null or empty". Your template should work if the data_submitted element exists and has no content, but it won't work if the data_submitted element doesn't exist. To handle both non-existence and emptiness, replace `data_submitted != ''` by `not(data_submitted = '')`. In fact, as a general rule, don't use "!=" in XSLT unless you are an expert and know exactly what it means.

Comment: By "null or empty" I meant that I have a data_submitted element, and it has no content, sorry, I didn't realize the semantic complications. Although you say that my code should work, it doesn't, hence my query, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Your mistake is testing if any `data_submitted` child of the current (`data_submitted`) node has a non-empty string value**. I guess that the `data_submitted` elements in the source XML document dont have any `data_submitted` children at all.

**Here is a complete and short solution** of your problem, just overriding the identity rule/template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="data_submitted/text()">
        <xsl:value-of select=
        "concat(substring(.,9),
                 '/',
                 substring(.,6,2),
                 '/',
                 substring(.,1,4)
             )
  "/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied to the following XML document**:

```
<t>
  <a/>
  <b>
     <data_submitted>2011-06-07</data_submitted>
     <data_submitted/>
    </b>
    <data_submitted>1912-05-12</data_submitted>
    <c/>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<t>
   <a/>
   <b>
      <data_submitted>07/06/2011</data_submitted>
      <data_submitted/>
   </b>
   <data_submitted>12/05/1912</data_submitted>
   <c/>
</t>
```

**Explanation**:

1. **The identity template copies every node "as-is"**
2. **A single template is overriding the [identity rule](http://dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)** -- for the text-node children of any `data_submitted` element. The code here produces the wanted transformed date. All other nodes, even including empty `data_submitted` elements are processed by the identity rule and are copied "as-is" to the output.

**Remember**: In many cases it isn't necessary to use any XSLT conditional instructions.

Use the power of XSLT templates and pattern-matching.

Comment: Actually I want to retain all the elements, as xml. I am transforming from xml to xml, just reversing the dates. I even want to retain the empty element. I'm afraid I wasn't all that clear.

Comment: @user736437: So, just add the identity rule.

Comment: @user736437: I have updated my solution to reflect your new requirements. :)

Comment: +1 it wasnt so obvious to me that "if" is not necessary at all :)

Answer (score 0):

Generally when testing if a node exists, you put the xpath expression in your "test" statement.  Without seeing your xml, I would guess that you can simply remove the "!= ''" and you should be fine.